# Turn a number into an array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, numbers

Say for instance I have the number 12:

```
var number = 12;
```

How could I change that number into something like:

```
var n = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone probably has a jQuery shortcut, but here's a plain JavaScript solution:

```
var num = 12;
var n = [];
for (var i=0; i <= num; i++) {
  n.push(i);
}
```

As a function:

```
function num2Array(num) {
  var n = [];
  for (var i=0; i <= num; i++) {
    n.push(i);
  }
  return n;
}

console.log(num2Array(15));
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: I literally need to create a variable like the `var n` in the question

Comment: @tfbox The function option doesn't work for you? Added possibly after your comment

Answer (score 3):

I actually had this function sitting around:

```
function number_range(beginning, end) {
    var numbers = [];
    for (; beginning <= end; beginning++) {
        numbers[numbers.length] = beginning; 
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

So if you need to generate more than one of these arrays, it could be useful:

```
var n = number_range(0, 12);
```

As for jQuery, well... I don't think that's necessary in this case. (I also don't know of any such function off the top of my head.)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't have this, but you could use underscore.js:

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#range

```
_.range([start], stop, [step])
```

So you could do:

```
var n = _.range(12);
```

Or:

```
var n = _.range(0, 12);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another JavaScript method

```
var number = 12, i = 0, n = [];
while( n.push( i++ ), i <= number );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an array just for iterate through you can doing this :
`Array(12).fill('');`

You just need finding the `index` from a loop fn to retrieve the current number.